# Включение и отключение объекта в коде С# Unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity3d

При нажатии на кнопку "K" объект должен появлятся обратно, но он не появляется (в консоле ошибок нету).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Name : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject GBJ;

// Update is called once per frame

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Space)) {
        SetFalse();
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.K)) {
        SetTrue();
    }
}

public void SetFalse () {
    GBJ.SetActive(false);
}

public void SetTrue () {
    GBJ.SetActive(true);
}
```

}

Comment: А `.SetActive(false)` проходит успешно?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Да нормально работает

Answer (score 1):

**Код рабочий**

**Проблема**,возможно,в том что вы скрипт накинули на кнопку,а при "исчезновении" кнопки 
со сцены перестают работать и все скрипты весящие на ней(объекте).

**Решение**: повесьте скрипт на canvas либо какой-нибудь пустой объект с глобальными скриптами